# how to make a third drop down based on what was selected in the previous two drop downs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to make a third drop down based on what was selected in the previous 2 drop downs. Currently I have two tables. 1st table has the production name, second table contains the date and time. When a particular production is selected the date is shown based on the production. the problem I am running into now is how to make a a third drop down for time which is based on the production and date. Below is my code for date.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET["perform"]))
    {
    require "opendb.php";

    $perform = $_GET["perform"];

        $query = "SELECT PerfDate FROM Performance
        INNER JOIN Production ON
        Performance.Title = Production.Title
        WHERE Production.Title LIKE '{$perform}'";
        $data = mysqli_query($con, $query);


    $date = array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data))
    {
        array_push($date, $row["PerfDate"]);
    }

        echo json_encode($date);

            require "closedb.php";
    }

?>
```

here is my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("getProduction.php", success = function(data)
    {
        var options = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            options += "<option value='" + data[i].toLowerCase() + "'>" + data[i] + "</option>"
        }

        $("#production").html("");
        $("#production").append(options);

    });

    $("#production").change(function()
    {
        $.getJSON("getDate.php?perform=" + $(this).val(), success = function(data)
    {
        var options = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            options += "<option value='" + data[i].toLowerCase() + "'>" + data[i] + "</option>"
        }

        $("#date").html("");
        $("#date").append(options);

        });
    });

});
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @JayBlanchard  
I am trying to make a third drop down for time, which shows the option based on the production and date selected. How would I do that? Date and time are in the same table